# Can a blog owner trace my IP address when I use incognito mode?

Tags: web-browser, safe-browsing-filter

I access a blog hosted by blogspot using Incognito mode. I comment on one of the posts, by signing into my Gmail account (as the blogger does not allow Anonymous comments). If I comment by visiting the blog on an Incognito window, will the blog owner have access to my IP address and location?

If yes, is there a way to guard my IP and location from being visible to the blog owner?

Comment: IP address is a real and important part of the Internet. you use it to tell machine "a" where you are in the big inter-network we call Internet. So guarding against the targeted machine "a" knowing your IP is a bit problematic. there are use-cases where you would want to employ this but you should always consider whether these things should be published at all VPN's can only partially hide your location (the traffic does have to get back to you after all). And the way they try to hide is is by exposing there own IP address. Basically an IP is public while in transit, as long as its not stored.

Comment: From the Chrome Incognito blank page: "However, you aren’t invisible. Going incognito doesn’t hide your browsing from your employer, your Internet service provider or the websites that you visit."

Comment: Your IP is not tied to a very specific location the way that the GPS on your phone or wifi-triangulation might work. A website like this one will be able to tell you about how exact your location can be determined from your IP: http://iplocation.com/

Comment: Incognito is a misnomer. It's just a way to avoid saving the history, so when you type something in the address bar in front of someone else, nothing weird will hopefully show up. It may also be useful to test stuff without being affected by the cache (like ranking in search results, etc.). AFAIK, it has no other purposes.

Answer (score 14):

> If I comment by visiting the blog on an Incognito window, will the blog owner have access to my IP address and location?

Yes. Incognito mode just stops your browser from keeping history.

> If yes, is there a way to guard my IP and location from being visible to the blog owner?

You can use a VPN or anonymyzing proxy.

Comment: I hear it is great to check flight prices using Incognito mode, since they won't keep track of you. Is that all gibberish, given Incognito mode affects only the client's browser settings?

Comment: @Abraham  Learn about cookies, and how they can affect websites.

Comment: @Abraham... Using Incognito will not help regarding Flight prices issue as in one of my web development project I was getting clients IP even if he was using incognito mode... You need to use VPN or Tor browser...

Answer (score 2):

The blog owner will not see your IP however they might see your Google profile. Blogspot does not offer any way of identifying the IP of a person leaving a comment but if the owner decides to investigate your profile he might eventually get further information that could compromise you.

Comment: How does the owner not see the visitors IP address in his server logs?

Comment: The owner in the case of Blogspot is Google. So yes Google could see the IP but not the owner of the blog.

Comment: Is it not possible to monitor IP addresses using Statcounter, by setting around a narrow range of time interval and observing the activity?

Comment: "The blog owner will not see your IP however they might see your Google profile" <== Totally false. Dont forget that IP is "transport level" asset. Transport keeps being transport, regardless upper protocol. When you connect throught IP to a server to access a ressource, then targetted server has your IP (unless you use VPN : then, VPN provider has your IP and server has VPN IP...)

Comment: @binarym in this case, as was pointed out, the server is owned by Google, not the person writing the blog. The blogger is just using a web app to publish a blog and doesn't have access to server logs, so "totally false" is a little strongly worded. Although as Bravo pointed out you can use stat counters and email notifications to get around this, as a blogger.

Comment: @dwizu  : ok, my bad ... sorry. After reading better, yeah, since there's no way to get HTTP server logs or to push some PHP/cgi-bin/whatever script, i guess there's no way but Google's stat system to get visitor IP. Nevertheless, OP must remind that if his comment on blogspot is breaking some law, then Google will help authority to track him and, as the operator of the service, Google have his IP address ...

Answer (score 2):

> will the blog owner have access to my IP address and location?

It depends on multiple factors. Are you running a VPN to block your current IP Address? Did the website owner have a plugin or software on their website to help them trace visitors IP Addresses? (opentracker.net).

Most of those questions you don't have answers to. Your best bet is to always use a VPN if you are afraid of individuals finding your IP Address. A great tool to use after installing a VPN is [MyIPSpy](https://www.myipspy.com) . It is a free tool that allows individuals to see their IP Address, along with their exact location on a map.

Comment: "Did the website owner have a plugin or software on their website to help them trace visitors IP Addresses?" No need of that: every HTTP servers has access logs that track IP, timestamp, user agent , etc... for every accessed ressources .... This is the basis of HTTP servers.